# Access denied when pushing gem using Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine, rubymine-7

I'm developing a Ruby Gem using RubyMine 1.7.4, I have already build the gem but when I try to push it I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /usr/bin/gem push dogeify-1.0.0.gem -k 4393c168a8a078a5008e4697b800276a
Enter your RubyGems.org credentials.
Don't have an account yet? Create one at https://rubygems.org/sign_up

HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have seen an issue similar to this [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/gem-release/issues/19), but the difference is that I never get a chance of writing my user name or password.

I also tried creating a `~/.gem/credentials` file using the command given by RubyGems and it shows no error but if I open the file all I see is this:

```
HTTP Basic: Access denied.
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this error?

Comment: Is it so necessary to push a gem from inside rubymine?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`?

Comment: I could push it from outside, but I'm trying to learn how to use Rubymine.

Comment: I had the same issue when pushing my very first gem. Problem was that I didn't confirm my email adress yet. After I did that, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I edited the `~/.gem/credentials` file from outside Rubymine to make it look like this:

```
:rubygems_api_key: "personal_key"
--- 
:rubygems_api_key: API_KEY
```

Once that was done, I try to publish the gem and it worked.

Anyway, I still don't know what is causing the error.